Zendesk web widget position settings does not work in non-classic
below settings works for zendesk classic web widget but not for zendesk webwidget sdk.
zE('webWidget', 'updateSettings', {
        webWidget: {
          color: {
            theme: '#0a0713',
            launcherText: '#ffffff',
          },
          position: {horizontal: 'left'},
        },
      });

is there any new settings to change position in webwidget sdk?
documentation is not updated https://developer.zendesk.com/api-reference/widget-messaging/web/core/

Zendesk's Messaging widget location customisation can be achieved by in-product settings by going to admin console -> Channels > Messaging > Style tab. Screen shot of how it looks:
[
